# Standard deviation and median for given data range only

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr

I would like to take the standard deviation and median of the rows based on the condition in another column.

lets say I would like to take the `x` column's standard deviation (`sd`) only the values in between `main+1` and `main-1` range and same thing for the `median`.

So I tried

```
set.seed(2000)

df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10,5,sd=2),main=4)

> df
          x main
1  3.292314    4
2  4.294221    4
3  6.780299    4
4  8.482573    4
5  6.832157    4
6  2.646797    4
7  1.123124    4
8  9.188757    4
9  5.450950    4
10 7.352552    4
```

So I did

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
mutate(sd_range=sd(x[main+2&main-2]),med_range=median(x[main+1]))



        x main sd_range med_range
1  3.292314    4 2.644843  6.832157
2  4.294221    4 2.644843  6.832157
3  6.780299    4 2.644843  6.832157
4  8.482573    4 2.644843  6.832157
5  6.832157    4 2.644843  6.832157
6  2.646797    4 2.644843  6.832157
7  1.123124    4 2.644843  6.832157
8  9.188757    4 2.644843  6.832157
9  5.450950    4 2.644843  6.832157
10 7.352552    4 2.644843  6.832157
```

it's strange because when I check `sd` of the x values `main+2&main-2` manually

```
x <- c(3.29,4.29,2.64,5.45)

> sd(x)
[1] 1.226523
```

Cannot understand why condition is not working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need `x[x <= main+2 & x <= main-2]`, for example

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks. That is I was looking for! I guess  the second should be `>=` :)

Comment: yup.  you're right about that.  good catch.